# hook_node_view strange behaviour

Tags: php, drupal

I'm using hook_node_view to display to content of a node instead of another one.

```
function mymodule_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($node->nid == 89) {
    $room = node_load(90);

    $node->content['mymodule_additional_content'] = node_view($room);
  }
}
```

The template of node 90 displays "ROOM" text (for test).

But here is what is displayed instead of just "ROOM" :

> ROOM
>
> Language Français
>
> Gabarit:
>
> pages/chambres.tpl.php

Any idea ?

EDIT : if I replace line 5 by :

```
    $node->content = array('mymodule_additional_content' => node_view($room));
```

Thus removing all other content previously added to $node->content, I get that result :

> ROOM
>
> Language Français

That means that "Language Français" is added AFTER the hook is called. But where ?

Comment: I am too. Too much mistery to make a good question.

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to do exactly, but in terms of performance, I'd advice NOT to do this way. Create a node template node--89.tpl.php and add your custom stuff there.

Comment: Actually, it's the better solution I was told in this thread : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49025/how-to-do-a-redirection-in-drupal

What I show here is a sample, in the real case "90" must be found dynamically.

Comment: Try adding a view mode to the `node_view()` call: `$node->content['mymodule_additional_content'] = node_view($room, 'teaser');`

Comment: @Clive: Doesn't work... 

Also I've edited my post.

Comment: It'll be another module that implements the same hook running after yours, so your changes get added to. Try following the [How to update a module's weight](http://drupal.org/node/110238) guide to make your module's hooks run after any others, that should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working answer from @Clive :

It'll be another module that implements the same hook running after yours, so your changes get added to. Try following the How to update a module's weight guide to make your module's hooks run after any others, that should do the trick.